# How to know which appengine quota was exceeded historically

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-compute-engine

I use the Google Datastore service from app engine and from compute engine.

During the night I see that some of the compute engine scripts have surpassed a quota (got a python google.api_core.exceptions.TooManyRequests: 429 Quota exceeded exception)

With the following python exception:

```
pytongrpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with (StatusCode.RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED, Quota exceeded.)>
```

After my quota is exceeded, my whole appengine application becomes unavailable and returns 503 error on every request.
I want to understand which script is responsible for this.

1. Is there a way to see which quota was surpassed from the actual api that triggered the suppression?
2. Is there a way to look at past quota data (before today) to see which quota was exceeded?
3. Is there a way to get an alert from google cloud, warning about a
   close quota overuse?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've probably set a daily spending limit on App Engine (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/console/#setting_a_spending_limit).  If your GCP project hits this budget then you'll start getting out of quota errors.  You may want to switch from a daily budget to budget alerts (https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets).